# Base64 encoding a .Rda file

Tags: r, save, base64, rda

All,

I'm trying to figure out how to put a .Rda file into Base64 encoding for it to be shipped to and from an API. I am really struggling with how to do this. Here's what I've got, but I think it's way off target:

```
cuse <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat", header=TRUE)

lrfit <- glm( cbind(using, notUsing) ~ age + education + wantsMore , family = binomial, data=cuse)

filename <- "C:/test.Rda"

save(lrfit, file=filename)

library("base64enc")
tst <- base64encode(filename)
save(tst, file="C:/encode.Rda")

base64decode(file="C:/encode.Rda", output = "C:/decode.Rda")
```

When I try to open the decode.Rda file, it throws a magic number error. Like I said, I think I'm way off base here, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please also provide the exact error message.  It might help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a correct sequence of steps that should allow for the correct encoding/decoding

```
#sample data
dd<-iris
fn <- "test.rda"
fnb4 <- "test.rdab64"

#save rda
save(iris, file=fn)

#write base64 encoded version
library(base64enc)
txt <- base64encode(fn)
ff <- file(fnb4, "wb")
writeBin(txt, ff)
close(ff)

#decode base64 encoded version
base64decode(file=fnb4, output = "decode.rda")
(load("decode.rda"))
# [1] "iris"
```

The problem was your second `save()`. That was creating another RDA file with the base64 data encoded inside. It was not writing a base64 encoded version of the RDA file to disc.