# minimize code for base64 decoding of rds object

Tags: r

I have R object (saved as .rds file) in base64-encoded string:

```
encoded <- "H4sIAAAAAAAABoVQywrCMBBc8zi0ICiCPyHme7yVrU0hkEZIA/XofwvWTUwQc/Ewy2SyOzvJpQUABpwxYJwoP1DZEHYECQKaeD5nwnHqa+1LTgCCpfGPIB1Oes5eReSD8VVf42+LKr3bmOdBZV3XZ214tTgXQ5bFdsCAKmBv9Y8yenKsDPbKuKC9Q6tmbUevRxKPGa+MP2mlcYO+0/6YFOrLrksT6RkyI36nSInJsCx6A7sXoh15AQAA"
```

I need to load this object in R. Following this SO question ("[Base64 encoding a .Rda file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874266/base64-encoding-a-rda-file/)"), I came to the following code:

```
library("base64enc")
conb64 <- file('obj.b64', 'w+b')
write(encoded, conb64);
close(conb64)

base64decode(file='obj.b64', output = 'obj.rds')
myobj <- readRDS('obj.rds')
```

This works fine but I would like to minimize the code and ideally manage without creating disk files, something like `myobj <- readRDS(base64decode(encoded))`. Is there any way to remove at least some operations?

It seems for me that there's a bug in `base64enc` package. Can be reproduced by simple executing `base64decode(what='anything', output = 'any.name')` - gives an error:

> Error in base64decode(what="anything", output = "any.name") :
>   argument "file" is missing, with no default

apparently it happens because `base64decode()` use `file` as an argument but also calls a `file()` function. When I changed the source of the function (replaced `file` to `filename`), everything worked correctly and code `decoded <- base64decode(encoded, what = 'raw')` gives correct binary rds file. While the bug is not corrected, one can use the function of the same name from `caTools` package: `decoded <- base64decode(z = encoded, what = 'raw')`. However, I failed to feed this to `readRDS()` function:

```
library('caTools')
decoded <- base64decode(encoded, what = 'raw')
con1 <- rawConnection(object = dec, open = 'rb')
myobj <- readRDS(con1)
# Error in readRDS(con1) : unknown input format
```

Comment: May I ask, what's the purpose of the having base64-encoded RDS files? Just curious...

Comment: well, originally it was just for the purpose of attaching an R object in another SO question :) There is no way to attach binary object here, and I did not want to upload the file to some hosting

Comment: ah, I see... Thank you