# Send an R (heterogeneous) list object as binary as a reply to a REST request, using plumber

Tags: r, rest, base64

I would like to send a complex heterogeneous list object in binary form as a reply to a REST request to the R service (using plumber), so that when decoded on the other side it converts back to its original list format.

So far, I have managed to do it using intermediate RDS files by reading through and slightly modifying [Base64 encoding a .Rda file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874266/base64-encoding-a-rda-file/).

A MWE explaining my efforts and issues follows:

```
foodata <- list('a' = 1,
                'b' = 'hello world',
                'pi' = 3.14,
                'strvec' = letters[1:5],
                'intvec' = 1:5,
                'df' = data.frame('df1' = letters[1:5], 'df2' = 1:5),
                'z' = 26)


fn <- "test.rds"
fnb4 <- "test.rdsb64"
decoded <- "decoded.rds"
saveRDS(foodata, file = fn, compress = F)

#write base64 encoded version
library(base64enc)
txt <- base64enc::base64encode(fn)

#decode base64 encoded version
rdsbin <- base64enc::base64decode(txt)

# how to convert rdsbin back to the foodata list without using the intermediate step of saving to a file as follows?
ff <- file(decoded, "wb")
writeBin(rdsbin, ff)
close(ff)

bardata <- readRDS(decoded)

print(identical(foodata, bardata))
# [1] TRUE
```

Is there any way to avoid the reads/writes of the intermediate files? Or a completely different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need intermediate files, you can use a `rawConnection` to do these types of operations in memory

```
#encore to base64 text string
encode_stream <- rawConnection(raw(), "r+")
saveRDS(foodata, file = encode_stream)

seek(encode_stream, 0) #reset to beginning of file
txt <- base64enc::base64encode(encode_stream)
close(encode_stream)


# txt is now a string that contains the data
# encoded in base64


# decode string to R object
rdsbin <- base64enc::base64decode(txt)
decode_stream <- rawConnection(rdsbin, "r")

bardata <- readRDS(decode_stream)
close(decode_stream)

# verify result
print(identical(foodata, bardata))
# [1] TRUE
```